# A calculus and algebra problem

Tags: calculus

If $a_1$, $a_2$...,$a_n$ be the roots of $f(x)=0$ and $A_1$, $A_2$,...,$A_t$ be the roots of $f'(x)=0$.
Prove that 
$f'(a_1)×f'(a_2)...×f'(a_n)= n^n×f(A_1)×f(A_2)...×f(A_t)$

$f'$ represents first derivative of $f(x)$

I think we can prove each of these equal to some other constant.

Comment: Are you assuming that there are the same number of roots of the derivative as the function?  In other words, are these all the roots?  Is $f$ a function from reals to reals?

Comment: @user481779 I just had a look at your profile : I have seen that you never validate good answers : this is a bad habit. You have to do it systematically (unless no answer is satisfying), say a fortnight after your question has been asked (which correponds to a time where the question isn't likely to have new answers). It is by this discipline that this site works.

Comment: For example, the answer to your question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583450) is a perfect one : you should validate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I begin, I'll note that you haven't quite provided complete information. What is $f$? Is it a polynomial? Is it $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}\RR\to \RR$ and differentiable once? Differentiable infinitely many times? Analytic? Is it $\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}\CC\to\CC$ and holomorphic?

It turns out that this formula only works (with a slight modification) when $f$ is a polynomial, I've provided a counterexample for the other conditions below.

**Case 1: $f$ is a polynomial, $f'$ is its formal derivative.**
*(Note that we can assume we are working over an algebraically closed field in this case)*

First note that if $f$ has a repeated root, then it will also be a root of $f'$, so both sides will be 0. Also note that $f'$ should have one less root than $f$, since its degree is one less than the degree of $f$. Thus we can assume that $f=c\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)$, where all the $a_i$ are distinct. Then $f' = cn\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x-A_i)$.
Thus 
$$cn^n\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f(A_i) 
= n^nc^n \prod_{i,j\in[1,n-1]\times[1,n]}(A_i-a_j)$$
$$
= \prod_{j=1}^n cn(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_j-A_i)
$$
$$
= (-1)^{n(n-1)}\prod_{j=1}^n f'(a_j)
= \prod_{j=1}^n f'(a_j).
$$
In the special case when $f$ is monic, your statement holds. Unless I've made an error in my algebra somewhere.
Note that the product $$\prod_{i,j\in [1,n-1]\times[1,n]}(A_i-a_j)$$ is related to the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of $f$, or equivalently the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)
of $f$ and $f'$, so this result could probably be expressed in those terms as well.

**Case 2: $f:\CC\to\CC$ is holomorphic (or worse).**

In this case, it is false.
Consider $f(z)=ze^z$, $f'(z)=ze^z+e^z=(z+1)e^z.$ $a_1=0$, $A_1=-1$. So
$f'(a_1)=1\ne 1^1\cdot f(A_1)=-1/e$.

Note that in this example $f$ and $f'$ have each have a single real zero, so this counterexample is also a counter example for $f : \RR\to\RR$ with any degree of smoothness.

Comment: You are assuming that $f$ is a polynomial.  That is not stated in the problem.  As you say, it is ruled out by the statement that there are the same number of roots of the derivative and the function itself.

Comment: [+1] Excellent answer ! It's true that one could at once apply the theorem giving the different forms of the resultant (more precisely the discriminant), but it is very pedagogical to prove it again as you did !

Comment: @RossMillikan Good point. I had made that assumption, probably because root implies zero of a polynomial to me, and zeroes is the word used for the same concept for other functions in my local math English. Give me a bit to think about it and I'll edit.

Comment: @RossMillikan I've added a counterexample to show that this only (almost) makes sense when $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Well done.  A good example.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.I ve edited the question

Comment: @user481779, your question is still confusing, and I think my answer still addresses your question. If you have a specific question about my answer feel free to ask.